# Accessing model attributes from application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model: **message**, and i want that all user can be able to save description and I want something along all the App, bat i get error   :  **Rails undefined method `model_name'**. 
It seems that he can not identify the model from: application.html.erb

**_header.html.erb**

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Bag</a>
    <ul>
    <%= simple_form_for (message) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.text_field :description , as: :text %>
      <%= f.submit "Save" %>
    </div>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag"application" , :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' , message: @​message%>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: What is @​message in application controller?

Comment: Is your model inherited from ActiveRecord::Base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up a before_filter in your application controller

```
before_filter :message

private
def message
  @message = Message.new
end
```

now this action will be executed on every request and will be available application wide

In your _header.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for message, url: message_path, method: :post  do |f| %>
```

it will submit to MessagesController#create

In your MessagesController

```
skip_before_action :message

def create
 # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Partial**

The error will be with your [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) call in your [`partial`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

--

Currently, you're calling the partial like this:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' , message: @​message%>
```

This will likely **not pass the variable** you need, consequently preventing `simple_form_for` to pull the `model` name from the object (which it requires).

To give you an explanation, the `simple_form_for` method builds on top of the `form_for` method in Rails, which in turn uses the `@objects` you send it to build the `<form>` in its entirety:

> `form_for` generates an appropriate form tag and yields a form builder
>   object that knows the model the form is about. Input fields are
>   created by calling methods defined on the form builder, which means
>   they are able to generate the appropriate names and default values
>   corresponding to the model attributes, as well as convenient IDs, etc.
>   Conventions in the generated field names allow controllers to receive
>   form data nicely structured in params with no effort on your side.

Succinctly, it means that if you're going to use `simple_form_for` (and by virtue, `form_for`), you need to pass a valid Ruby / Rails object to the form. I believe your miss-calling of the partial will prevent this from happening.

---

**Fix**

You'll need to do the following:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header', locals: { message: @message } %>
```

This *should* pass the correct data to the form, presuming, of course, that the data exists to begin with. To ensure this is the case (as I see you're using it as part of your *layout*), you'll need to invoke the `@message` variable each time you call an action:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_message

   private

   def set_message
      @message = Message.new
   end
end
```

This will set the `@message` variable every time - giving you the ability to call it & apply it to the `form_for` each time you load a page.